# Library to parse and convert SWIFT MT files

Tags: java, swift-mt, mt940

In order to read and parse MT942, MT940 files, which library is recommended to use.

I came across two options,

1. Using open-source library provided by [PROWIDE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.prowidesoftware/pw-swift-core)
2. Using SWIFT standard libraries - [SWIFT](https://www.swift.com/our-solutions/compliance-and-shared-services/mystandards/mystandards-base-libraries/features)

Is there any other approach to read and parse SWFIT MT files ? Or which is considered best approach to parse and convert MT files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of the Prowide library.

A major benefit of our library is that it is open source and widely used.

SWIFT base libraries can be very expensive for the average project budget.

Comment: @DAIRAV We use Prowide Core library in one of our large projects and have been very happy so far. The API is clean and clear. There are also good examples online. And if you need support, there's GItHub (Prowide Core is hosted there). Support via GitHub works also really well! I would definitively recommend it. Thanks Sebastian! :thumbsup:

Comment: @sebastian-zubrinic, Are you providing an option for getting swift proprietary XML?

Comment: @TukaramBhosale yes. There is a default XML conversion in the open source https://www.prowidesoftware.com/resources/SWIFT-XML then for proprietary XML structures you can take a look at the commercial complementary library https://www.prowidesoftware.com/products/integrator/my-format which can handle conversions between MT/ISO20022 and any proprietary XML, CSV or FIXED-LENGTH structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [FINaplo](https://finaplo.paymentcomponents.com/financial-messages), a multi-purpose implementation for financial messages.

It provides an online validation service, Java SDKs, as well as REST solutions.

I happen to be one of the authors.

For this specific case, the most suitable answer is a SWIFT MT library, you can check a demo on this [GitHub Page](https://github.com/Payment-Components/demo-swift-mt).